# Why am I getting a exception error when I print my results out?

Tags: java, arrays

I am essentially trying to create a 2 x 10 2d array that replaces the first row with 0 but every time I run it only gives me the first two values. I'm fairly certain it's correct but I want the whole array to also display the values I put in. I'm still relatively new to Java and would like to know how I could fix this. Thanks!
**CODE**

public class QuestionTwo {
public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int[][] table = { {20, 16}, {1, 23}, {9, 46}, {73, 8}, {95, 18}, {67, 0}, {13, 24}, {36, 69}, {21, 55}, {48, 56} 
    };
    

    
    for (int c =0; c < 2; c ++) {

             for (int r=0; r < 10; r++) {

               table[r][c] = 0;
            
    System.out.println(table[c][r]);
        }
    }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide the code inside the question, not as an attached image. That's a bad practice in SO.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 10 element array of two element arrays.

Your outer loop goes from 0 to 1, and your inner loop goes from 0 to 9.
Your inner loop is iterating over 2-element arrays and when you reach 2 it get's out of bounds exception trying to access 3rd element of 2 element array.

You need to switch your iterators around so that you first iterate 0-9 and inner goes 0-1.

Comment: hello thank you for the advice and I am sorry for posting an image rather than the code. I'll be sure to not make this mistake when posting again

Answer (score 0):

Because you are doing it the other way round.

```java
int[][] myArray = {{0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}, {0,0}};
```

results in an array like this `int[4, 2]`, and you are iterating like if it were `int[2, 4]`. Swap the iteration values.

Comment: okay thank you, and I also apologize for not following the correct guidelines for posting. This is my first time ever using stackoverflow and I will be more conscious of my questions.

Comment: No worries. Now it looks ok, I removed the downvote :)